# How to create a circular list of a given length from a list

Tags: python, list, slice, python-itertools, circular-list

I'm in need of a circular list. I have a list of 5 tags:

```
taglist = ["faint", "shocking", "frosty", "loved", "sadness"]
```

I have another list with monotonically increasing values:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

I want to create another list using the `taglist` by the length of `list`. If `list` has 7 items, I want a new list of tags like below.

```
newtaglist = ["faint", "shocking", "frosty", "loved", "sadness","faint", "shocking"]
```

And this list will go on like that as circular filling. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`newtaglist` can be generated using a modulo operator to make sure the index is in range

```
taglist = ["faint", "shocking", "frosty", "loved", "sadness"]
num_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
newtaglist = [taglist[i % len(taglist)] for i in xrange(len(num_list))]
```

Yielding:

```
['faint', 'shocking', 'frosty', 'loved', 'sadness', 'faint', 'shocking']
```

Run it [here](https://repl.it/JodP)

Comment: In case you care about runtime, this is actually the slowest method, about 10x slower than all the others [which are fairly similar in the example I've linked to](https://repl.it/JpkQ).

Comment: Thanks for the codes from repl ... ! So, stefans use of divmod is the  fastest one.

Answer (score 15):

The easiest way is use [*itertools.cycle*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) which was designed for this particular purpose.

```
>>> from itertools import cycle, islice
>>> baselist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
>>> taglist = ["faint", "shocking", "frosty", "loved", "sadness"]
>>> list(islice(cycle(taglist), len(baselist)))
['faint', 'shocking', 'frosty', 'loved', 'sadness', 'faint', 'shocking']
```

Another way is to multiply (repeat) the list to make it large enough, then slice-off any excess:

```
>>> baselist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
>>> taglist = ["faint", "shocking", "frosty", "loved", "sadness"]
>>> n = len(baselist)
>>> (taglist * -(n // -len(taglist)))[:n]
['faint', 'shocking', 'frosty', 'loved', 'sadness', 'faint', 'shocking']
```

The double-negation is used to convert floor-division to ceiling-division which rounds-up whenever there is a remainder.  That makes sure the list multiplication always gives at least as many elements as needed.

Comment: Using the multiply method seems good for me, new way of learning of newthings.

Answer (score 3):

Also, in python `list` is built-in function, dont use `list` as variable name.

```
taglist = ["faint", "shocking", "frosty", "loved", "sadness"]
print(len(taglist))
list_ = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
print(len(list_))

diff = len(list_) - len(taglist)

for i in range(0, diff):
  taglist.append(taglist[i])
print(taglist)
```

Comment: Although it isn't in the question, if he wants to loop more than once through the list, this will fail. I think adding a `tag_length = len(taglist)` before the loop and then `taglist.append(taglist[i % tag_length])` might fix that. Didn't test it though. **Edit** something like this, but I think this goes the wrong direction through the list...

Answer (score 3):

Multiplying plus slicing:

```
>>> taglist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> length = 13
>>> 
>>> q, r = divmod(length, len(taglist))
>>> taglist * q + taglist[:r]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 2):

Where n is the desired length:

```
[taglist[i % len(taglist)] for i in range(n)]
```

Or you could use Raymond's suggestion of

```
from itertools import cycle
infiniteTagList = cycle(taglist)
[next(infiniteTagList) for i in range(n)]
```